# Display issue with date-picker from angular materials

Tags: angular, date, angular-material, datepicker

I tried to add a date-picker (the basic model) of angular materials to my project
https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview
However, the display I get is not what is represented on the site

The model with "Choose a date" written on it is the model I am supposed to get [Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVrIp.png)
However, the one I get is the one with "Date du match" written on it[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmdyI.png)

This is what my HTML looks like

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Date du match</mat-label>
  <input matInput [min]="minDate" [matDatepicker]="picker">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

I tried to solve the problem by touching the CSS of this component, but I can't get a result as clean as the one proposed by angular materials

```
mat-form-field {
  width: 12rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 3rem;
}

mat-datepicker-toggle {
  float: right;
}
```

With these modifications, this is the result I get
[Result obtained with the modifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7HI4.png)

Here is my app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AccueilComponent } from './accueil/accueil.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { IdentificationComponent } from './identification/identification.component';
import { CreationMatchComponent } from './creation-match/creation-match.component';
import { InscriptionComponent } from './inscription/inscription.component';
import { CompositionEquipeComponent } from './composition-equipe/composition-equipe.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { DropdownListJoueurComponent } from './dropdown-list-joueur/dropdown-list-joueur.component';
import { MatSelectModule } from "@angular/material/select";
import { BoutonComponent } from './bouton/bouton.component';
import { MatButtonModule } from "@angular/material/button";
import { InputTexteComponent } from './input-texte/input-texte.component';
import { MatInputModule } from "@angular/material/input";
import { MenuComponent } from './menu/menu.component';
import { MatMenuModule } from "@angular/material/menu";
import { MatIconModule } from "@angular/material/icon";
import { DatePickerComponent } from './date-picker/date-picker.component';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from "@angular/material/datepicker";
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { TimePickerComponent } from './time-picker/time-picker.component';
import { MatTableModule } from "@angular/material/table";
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AccueilComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    IdentificationComponent,
    CreationMatchComponent,
    InscriptionComponent,
    CompositionEquipeComponent,
    DropdownListJoueurComponent,
    BoutonComponent,
    InputTexteComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    DatePickerComponent,
    TimePickerComponent
  ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatDatepickerModule,
        MatNativeDateModule,
        MatTableModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think any thing is wrong with your `app.module.ts`

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import {MaterialExampleModule} from '../material.module';
import {DatepickerOverviewExample} from './datepicker-overview-example';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material/core';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [DatepickerOverviewExample],
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MaterialExampleModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [DatepickerOverviewExample],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Normally for the standard design you don't need to add any custom styles. Look at the official [example.](https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.ts)

Comment: Hi @Flo and thank you for your answer. I've added my app.module.ts in the description of the problem. I tried to add the dependencies you had that I didn't, but it still doesn't work. Is this what you were suggesting as a solution?

Comment: If you create a brand new project, import all the stuff and try it. If it will then work?